# Retroactively squashing a subtree merge

Tags: git

I merged an external library into my project using [the subtree merge strategy](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html). I didn't pass the --squash option to 'git merge', so I now have the entire library history (which is huge) bloating the repository. How can I retroactively squash the merge?

My situation is:

```
Z--Y--..--B--A
              \ 
           D---E---F---G master
```

I would like to get to:

```
           D---E---F---G master
```

Where E is the commit containing the merge.

I guess the solution will involve 'git rebase' but I'm not sure how to use it properly in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that if you already published E or later commits in master to remote, then DON'T do rebase on them, as this will break other's code and you'll need to manually fix their repositories too.

Rebase creates new revisions, it can't magically modify existing (that's why it uses SHA1, so you're sure that your commit contain what generated this particular SHA1 and is not modified)

But if you're prepared to it, then proceed with my example.

1. First you need to go back to commit right before you merged library, create named branch from there, let's say 'lib-squash'
2. `git merge --squash library`; `git commit`
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git rebase -i -p --onto lib-squash <sha1 old merge commit>`
5. optionally `git branch -D library` and `git branch -d lib-squash`

This leaves you with clean history, but you just rewrote history, you need to push with --force flag, and then every person would need to fix their repository:

1. `git fetch`
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git reset --hard origin/master`, assuming you don't have other local commits than in remote repository
4. if you have any local commits, you need to "rebase onto" these commits too.

Unfortunately I haven't found article about detaching historical commits without affecting future commits.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for your answer. Regarding your comment about not rebasing a published commit - assuming that everyone else have an up-to-date repository and are working on 'master', why should it bother them if commits Z-A disappear? Doesn't the commit E (and G) contains the entire tree they're working on?

Comment: They contain the same tree, but they still have another commit-ID (since the commit-ID depends on the commit's parents, too). This is the problem here.

Comment: Every commit generates sha1 from parent link (sha1), commit text and tree content. So even if your tree is the same, if you change commit text your sha1 should change too. And if you squash commits into one commit, then you basically change sha1 of subtree - you loose commit messages and parent links which were used to generate sha1s